# Listing network adapters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, networking

How can I list all the network adapters available on the computer, as well as their status and type. For instance:

Ethernet: Connected

AirPort: Off

FireWire: Not Connected

Bluetooth PAN: Connected

Just like the Network settings in OS X does.

Specifically I want to figure out if Bluetooth PAN Is connected or not.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use the System Configuration framework. Here's the [Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/) and [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/).

Comment: @user185813: If that worked for you, you should accept the answer to that others know that there is a correct answer and what it is.